# Unable to scrape other namespaces when using kube-prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator

Prometheus deployed using [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus) can't scrape resources on namespaces other than `default`, `monitoring` and `kube-system`. I added additional namespaces on my `jsonnet` as described in [kube-prometheus README](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus) but no success...

I also tried to create a new `ServiceMonitor` manually, but no success...

I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: can you validate the permissions of the service account so that it's actually capable of getting all resources of type `ServiceMonitor` in other namespaces?

Comment: Hi @RickRackow I created [PR](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/pull/114) to help clarify how to create the `ServiceMonitor` resources...

Comment: great work! Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

If you used the pre-compiled manifests [here](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus/blob/3c109369d4d4e19d2bab9e073797eb971a5eb957/manifests/prometheus-roleBindingSpecificNamespaces.yaml) you will only have your service account with 3 rolebindings allowing access to the namespaces you mentioned.

You can add more namespaces for example by applying the same `roleBinding` in more namespaces.

This is more secure as opposed to using a `clusterRoleBinding` since it allows for more finegrained permissions.